# Intercom Having to Double Click to have menu appear.

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intercom

I am having to double click my support button to have the intercom messenger to appear on the initial click

```js
    private handleSupportClick() {
        const ic = (window as any).Intercom;
        function l() {
            const d = document;
            const s = d.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/';
            const x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            (x as any).parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
        }
        (window as any).intercomSettings = {
            app_id: process.env.REACT_APP_INTERCOM_APP_ID as string,
            hide_default_launcher: true
        };
        (() => {
            l();
            if (typeof ic === "function") {
                ic('reattach_activator');
                ic('show', (window as any).intercomSettings);
            } else {
                const i = (...args: any) => {
                    (i as any).c(...args)
                };
                (i as any).q = [];
                (i as any).c = (args: any) => {
                    (i as any).q.push(args)
                };
                (window as any).Intercom = i;
                this.handleSupportClick();
            }
        })()
    }
```

.

After the initial click though, it will only take one click on my support button to summon the same messenger. I have tracked the flow in debugger literally line by line, yet I still cannot find why this requires a double click. I have, of course, made the function call itself again after the initial click, yet this still does not work and I get an error saying "CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object"

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add `load` event to the script, eg `s.onload = () => {//activation code}` or by `s.addEventListener('load', () => {//activation code})`

Comment: @finico thank you for the feedback! I will keep you posted.

Comment: @finico so I added window.addEventListener('load', () => { this.handleSupportClick(); }); to the self calling function on the button and am having the same problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not to `window`, but your created script element. I had wrote it as `s`. And you should pay your attention to the method you add that element to html `head` again and again to every click, so you should avoid that.